# DateTime Calender Header in SSRS not working when deployed

Tags: datetime, reporting-services, calendar, header, href

I have date time calendar control in SSRS that works fine on my localhost. When I deploy the calendar control, the header does not work. The header helps the user to select the months and years.

[image: SSRS DateTime Calendar Control]

Comment: What do you mean by "Header does not work"? does the highlighted bit not show up? What version of SSRS are you using? What browser are you using to view the reports in?

Comment: the highlighted bit is a click that changes the calendar in to months and then on another click it changes to years. I am using VS 2017 BI tools 15.5.2 Version.I am running reports on IE 11.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=select+years+in+calendar+control&rlz=1C1CHBF_enUS749US749&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjUwqKU3p_aAhXtUd8KHaMFDjcQ_AUIDSgE&biw=1536&bih=734#imgrc=c8XqC8Z-8CWulM:   Something like this.

Comment: I would appreciate if anyone could help me out to resolve this.